# Applepay - canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks returns NO for the first time app runs.

Tags: ios, iphone, applepay

[ApplePayManager canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks] returns NO when i try to run the app from xcode on the device with ios 9.0

Comment: The credit is set in wallet and is ready to use for apple pay.                         canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks method has this statement:                 return @[PKPaymentNetworkAmex, PKPaymentNetworkMasterCard, PKPaymentNetworkVisa]; But still it returns NO;

Answer (score 0):

Have updated Xcode to 7.3 and running on device with iOS 9.3. This issue got fixed for me.